# Will my custom table frame support a soapstone top?

Tags: construction, kitchen-counters, support

I’m having a custom dining table made. The base will be white oak and measure approximately 68x38. The top is going to be soapstone and is 3cm thick and weighs approximately 500 lbs. The stone fabricator says the table legs should support the top, but this makes me nervous. The person building the table said he can add 3-4 horizontal supports across the top of the table and it should be fine, but he isn’t familiar with stone tops, as his tables are made with wood tops. I’m nervous that the advice that the table will support it are not accurate. Will the supports the table maker is recommending be enough to support the soapstone top, or do you have any other advice?

Pic of example supports suggested.

I was going to have castor wheels that support 200 lbs each put into the legs of the table so I can move it if need be. If anyone sees issues w this, please let me know.

[Copied from answer]
I actually don’t have details as to the construction of the table. The woodworker who is making the table is out of state and I found him online bc he makes table bases in the style I’m looking for.

[image]

Comment: Can you give details or pics of the joinery between the leg and the apron?

Comment: Legs will support that mass vertically but they could well fall off when you try to push it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on these 3-4 horizontal supports? I suspect that 3-4 = -1 is about right.

Comment: Once again, please follow the [instructions here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your two accounts merged. That way, you'll be able to edit your own question without having to get it reviewed. At a minimum, return to the original device/browser - the cookies for your "Jen" account should still be there so you can register the account and edit. Also, follow up questions, such as the one you're trying to edit in, don't belong here - we work on a 1 question per question basis. Feel free to ask a new question with a link to this one for background.

Comment: L/360 for tile. L/720 for stone. So, 2x6s? Not w/e those are, unless they're old growth unobtainium.

Answer (score 3):

The 38" distance from long rail to long rail is okay for soapstone. The long rails from post to post look too flimsy. If they deflect too much, then the soapstone could reach its breaking point sagging along the top of them. The leg bracket connection with the long rail might benefit from an additional fastener.

**Soapstone spanning 38"**

Soapstone is supposed to have good flexural properties. The lowest modulus of rupture for soapstone that I was able to find from 3 different sources was a little over 10MPa. Converting to imperial, that's basically 1500 psi. This value is similar to the #2 softwoods. The self weight, of course, is higher than softwood, but the live load for a table surface is nothing like the live loads under which, say, a softwood floor gets designed.

One of the random internet sites that I found (the sites had moduli of rupture from 10 MPa up to something like 17 MPa) had a modulus for the orthogonal direction, and that was within about 1 MPa of the other direction's value. This suggests that soapstone is effectively isotropic and there's no weak-axis/strong-axis complexity to deal with.

For the demand on the table's old configuration, I'll leave an algebraic `x` with psi units in the expression for finding the maximum load:

D = (1/8)(500#/[(68in)(38in)] + x)(38in)^2(12in/ft) = 420 + 2200x (#-in/ft).

For capacity I've got the 1500 psi modulus of rupture which implies a capacity of

C = (1500psi)(1/6)(12in/ft)[(3cm)(1in/2.54cm)]^2 = 4200 (#-in/ft).

Setting D=C and solving for `x` provides (1.7psi)(12in/ft)^2 = 250 psf. It's a brittle material (I assume based on the "stone" part of its name), so there should be a substantial safety factor. I'm very uncomfortable choosing a safety factor without a data set with lots of samples. For a brittle material, a safety factor of 10 isn't unheard of and sounds conservative. 25 psf, then, is the maximum load.

**White oak rails spanning 68"**

Unfortunately there's very little information to approach this one. Assuming a 28" top-of-rail height, I scale that top rail at about 3" tall. Squinting at the tops of the short rails to compare to my 3" tall dimension, I peg the rail thickness at about 1" and assume that all the rails have the same thickness. Abusing the NDS Supplement for white oak material properties, where its values are for 2" and thicker, and assuming #1 grade, the soapstone self weight results in a demand/capacity ratio of 1.1. That's a fail under the NDS. I've been using your 500# weight, however, where I computed 400# as the actual soapstone weight. The 400# results in a demand/capacity ratio of 0.86. That leaves room for 4 psf of additional load (for comparison against the soapstone's 25 psf).

Assuming Select Structural grade white oak instead of #1 grade, the demand/capacity ratio for the soapstone weight alone goes down to 0.63, leaving room for 13 psf of additional load (for comparison against the soapstone's 25 psf).

Sadly, I suspect that the stiffness of the rails is the constraint that determines their adequate size, where the strength is just an afterthought to double check. What is adequate stiffness? That depends on the material properties of soapstone. The elastic modulus...meh. I'm bored and, TLDR, you're probably screwed.

**Legs**

Those legs are plenty stout. No buckling there.

By the time the weight of the soapstone shows up at the rail-to-leg connections, the 400# has been diluted to 200# at the connection between the long rail and the leg bracket in the worst case scenario. This actually might be a bit too much for the connections that I'm accustomed to seeing at that spot. If there are only 2 fasteners between the bracket and the long rail like I think I'm seeing in your image, then I would probably add an additional fastener.

If the builder's legs usually work for the lateral stability of a feather-weight top, then they should work fine here also. Suppose the table top moved 1/4" out of alignment with the leg bases under a 30# horizontal push. The weight of the table top acting eccentric to the leg bases registers as equivalent to an additional horizontal push of (0.25in)(400#)/(28in) = 4#. Yawn, although I suppose the bone crushing weight of the soapstone probably warrants a higher safety factor than the light spraining weight of a wood tabletop.

**Recommendations**

With adequate long rails, the table is capable of supporting the soapstone top without the soapstone cracking. The 38" free span between rails is fine. Are the current rails inadequate? With all of the assumptions behind the analysis, who knows. If all of the assumptions turn out to be conservative, then the long rails are inadequate, and I suggest beefing up the rails. My strategy would be converting each long rail into the web of a little I-beam by fastening a little steel or aluminum plate to the top and bottom of the rail. The plate would be skinnier than the rail, of course. There's just a shear flow computation that needs doing to figure out the exact fastener spacing.

As I mentioned earlier, I might add an additional fastener between the leg brackets and the long rails if there are only 2 fasteners now.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your table frame builder to put a few layers of 3/4" plywood on top of the table, then load it up to 6-700 pounds spread evenly across the top, let it sit for a week.

After a week, ask them to run a straight edge or string along the long stringers to check for any sag. If it doesn't have any sag, it's *probably* going to be just fine. Also, have them double check the legs to ensure they haven't splayed out any.

This is *not* a guarantee that there won't be long term issues, but it will help highlight anything that might crop up right away.